# Make the inline tag edit link more muted

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, inline-tag-editor

The inline tag edit link is now always visible for 10k+ users. It's a little distracting [and apparently that's not just me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374024/254830).

The comment upvote & flags were distracting too, and we got used to them... but I don't think that will happen with the new inline tag edit button. It's brightly colored, capitalised, and on some sites it's even bolded (RPG.SE pictured below):

[image]

This is unlike every other post action button and in fact every word in its vicinity except for post text & usernames. All of these mean it effectively draws tons of attention to itself by design.

The previous inline tag edit link was a muted colour and lowercase like all the other links.

I suggest the following changes to the inline tag edit link:

- it should be greyed out, lowercase, and never bold.
- it should say “edit tags” instead of just “edit” in order to avoid us having two different edit buttons near each other that say the same thing but do two different things.

Comment: Also on meta.so: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374024/can-we-hide-or-relocate-the-inline-tag-edit-button-please-this-is-distractin?cb=1 (cross site dupe)

Comment: It's also red and bold on Japanese.  We definitely need both of your suggested fixes.

Comment: It now says "Edit tags", which is good.  Now we just need the "greyed out, lowercase, and never bold" change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your report. Our next production build should remove the bold weighting on the "Edit tags" link. We decided to keep the color and capitalization for the following reasons:

1. Capitalizing the first letter follows our copy guideline of sentence
   casing. In cases where we haven’t followed this in the past, we
   update them as we come across them.
2. Links match site themes, which is also a best practice for us.